# A component is changing a controlled input of type email to be uncontrolled

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have the following component:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Button from 'material-ui/Button';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';
import {FormGroup, FormControlLabel} from 'material-ui/Form';
import Checkbox from 'material-ui/Checkbox';
import StringFunc from '../utils/StringFunc';
import _Array from 'lodash/array';
import _Collection from 'lodash/collection';

class SignUp extends React.Component {

  state = {
    oSignUp: {
      sName: '',
      sEmail: '',
      sEmailConf: '',
      sPw: '',
      bCondition: false,
    },
    bSubmit: true,
  };

  static propTypes = {
    bFluid: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    fHandleSignUp: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  };

  handleOnSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.fHandleSignUp(this.state.oSignUp);
  };

  handleOnChange = name => event => {
    this.setState({
      oSignUp: {
        [name]: event.target.value
      },
    }, () => {
      this.setState({bSubmit: this.areDataFulFilled(this.state.oSignUp)})
    });

  };

  handleOnCheck = name => (event, checked) => {
    this.setState({
      [name]: checked
    }, () => this.setState({bSubmit: this.areDataFulFilled(this.state.oSignUp)}));
  };

  areDataFulFilled = state => {
    const bFulFilled = _Array.concat(StringFunc.isEmpty(state.sName),
      StringFunc.isEmpty(state.sEmail),
      StringFunc.isEmpty(state.sEmailConf),
      StringFunc.isEmpty(state.sPw),
      !state.bCondition);

    return _Collection.reduceRight(bFulFilled, (a, b) => {
      return a || b
    }, false);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <form noValidate autoComplete='off' onSubmit={this.handleOnSubmit}>
        <TextField
          id="name"
          label="Name"
          type="text"
          fullWidth={this.props.bFluid}
          value={this.state.oSignUp.sName}
          onChange={this.handleOnChange("sName")}
          margin="normal"
        />
        <TextField
          id="email"
          label="Email"
          type="email"
          fullWidth={this.props.bFluid}
          value={this.state.oSignUp.sEmail}
          onChange={this.handleOnChange("sEmail")}
          margin="normal"
        />
        <TextField
          id="emailconf"
          label="Email confirmation"
          type="email"
          fullWidth={this.props.bFluid}
          value={this.state.oSignUp.sEmailConf}
          onChange={this.handleOnChange("sEmailConf")}
          margin="normal"
        />
        <TextField
          id="password"
          label="Password"
          type="password"
          fullWidth={this.props.bFluid}
          value={this.state.oSignUp.sPw}
          onChange={this.handleOnChange("sPw")}
          margin="normal"
        />
        <FormGroup>
          <FormControlLabel
            control={
              <Checkbox
                checked={this.state.oSignUp.bCondition}
                onChange={this.handleOnCheck("bCondition")}
                color='primary'
              />
            }
            label='I agree to terms'
          />
        </FormGroup>

        <Button type='submit'
                disabled={this.state.bSubmit}
                variant='raised'
                color='primary'
                fullWidth={this.props.bFluid}>
          Sign Up
        </Button>
      </form>
    )
  }
}

export default SignUp;
```

It looks as following:
[image]

As you can see, after enter a letter, it throws an error.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't you write this.setState({
      oSignUp[name]: event.target.value
    })... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is, During state update you are deleting all the keys from the oSignUp object, so after update oSignUp will have only one key (key of input field you are updating).

**Solution:**

During update of one key, you have to mention all other key-value pairs also. Use this:

```
 handleOnChange = name => event => {
    let value = event.target.value;

    this.setState(prevState => ({
      oSignUp: {

        ...prevState.oSignUp,         // =====> added this line

        [name]: value
      },
    }), () => {
      this.setState({bSubmit: this.areDataFulFilled(this.state.oSignUp)})
    });
};
```

Check this snippet, you will get a better idea:

```js
let data = {
  obj: {
     a: 1,
     b: 2,
  },
  temp: 'hello'
};

let newData = {
  ...data,
  // only a will be available in newdata to get all use ...obj also
  obj: {
    a: 2
  }
};

console.log('newData', newData);
```

Comment: Why `b` disappeared?

Comment: because obj will be redefined with only one key 'a', to use the other data of obj write it like this: `obj: {...data.obj, a: 10}`, what it will do is: it will use all other key-value pairs and just update only one key 'a' :)

Comment: facing any issue?

Comment: Yes, I've got `TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null`.